# Get the results of a subquery in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, greatest-n-per-group

How do you create a join to get the latest invoice for all customers?

```
Tables:
- Invoices
- Customers

Customers table has: id, last_invoice_sent_at, last_invoice_guid
Invoices table has: id, customer_id, sent_at, guid
```

I'd like to fetch the latest invoice for every customer and, with that data, update last_invoice_sent_at and last_invoice_guid in the Customers table.

Comment: put some data for reference and  expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `distinct on`. For a query soring by `customer_id` and then by `invoice`, it would return the first row for each distinct value indicated in `distinct on`. That is the rows with `*` below:

```
customer_id | sent_at     |
1           | 2014-07-12  | * 
1           | 2014-07-10  | 
1           | 2014-07-09  |
2           | 2014-07-11  | *
2           | 2014-07-10  |
```

So your update query could look like:

```
update customers
set last_invoice_sent_at = sent_at
from (
  select distinct on (customer_id)
    customer_id,
    sent_at
  from invoices
  order by customer_id, sent_at desc
) sub
where sub.customer_id = customers.customer_id
```

Answer (score 2):

@Konrad provided a flawless SQL statement. But since we are only interested in a single column, `GROUP BY` will be more efficient than [`DISTINCT ON`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564) (which is great to retrieve multiple columns from the same row):

```
UPDATE customers c
SET    last_invoice_sent_at = sub.last_sent
FROM  (
   SELECT customer_id, max(sent_at) AS last_sent
   FROM   invoices
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
WHERE sub.customer_id = c.customer_id;
```